# iOS 6 and continuous receiving udp package using gcdasyncsocket

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, udp, multicast, gcdasyncsocket

I have problem with continuous receiving udp package with gcdasyncsocket. It's like iP5 iOS6 and iP4 iOS6 receive package for 200-300 ms then stop for another 200-300 and start receiving again. I run some test with iPhone 5 iOS7, iPhone 4 iOS 6 and iPhone 5 iOS6. Results confirm that issue appears only with iOS 6.

[image: Tests]

Code is not something sophisticated, is simple as it can be, sending to broadcast adress "230.0.0.1", and receiver socket join to group "230.0.0.1".

Sender

```
_udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_udpSocket bindToPort:_port error:&error];
[_udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
-(void)processBuffer: (NSData*)data
{
    [_udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"230.0.0.1" port:_port withTimeout:-1 tag:tag];
    tag++;
}
```

Receiver

```
_udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if (![_udpSocket bindToPort:_port error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Binding to port %i: %@",_port,error);
}

if (![_udpSocket joinMulticastGroup:_address error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Joining to multicast groupu: %@",error);
}
if (![_udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        [_udpSocket close];

        NSLog(@"Error starting server (recv): %@", error);

    }
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
    NSLog(@"IGotData");
}
```

How can I continuously receive? Did you met a similar problem?

### Update

I run some test on with iP5 iOS7 -> 6.1 simulator and iOS 6.1 simulator -> iP5 iOS7. In both cases I have continuous receiving.

### Update v2

I run tests again but now with simulator 6.0 and again I have continuous receiving.

Answer (score 0):

GCDAsyncUdpSocket works asynchronously.. YOu need to use a sync UDP request to achieve the result you want..

Comment: Ok, I can't use GCDAsyncUDPSocket, what class I should use then for sync UDP?